# Writing computed data to a txt/csv after each iterations step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, save

Consider the following simple example:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = 0, 0, 0, 0
index = 0

for i in range(3):
    index += 1
    x1 += 2
    x2 += 2
    x3 += 2
    x4 += 2
```

How can i create a txt or csv file that stores x1,x2,x3,x4 and index after each iteration in separate columns (5 in total). Is it also possible to give each column a title?

The end result should look like

```
Index    Data1    Data2    Data3    Data4  
1        2        2        2        2
2        4        4        4        4
3        6        6        6        6
```

It is important that the stored data is well separated because it will be later used for another computation. If the variable with the stored values is called " data_ " , i want to apply slice operations, e.g. data_[:,0] = [1,2,3].

---

Edit: 
@abc i tried your method but it does not work

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array

index = 0 

for i in range(3):
    index += 1
    x1 += 2
    x2 += 2
    x3 += 2
    compact = [[index, x1, x2, x3]]
    pd.DataFrame(compact, columns=   ['Index','Data1','Data2','Data3']).to_csv('example.csv',index=False)
```

The example.csv file will only obtain the last computed values, e.g.

[image]

In my real program it is not possible to first store all the computed values (10^6 iterations) and only afterwards to save them. The values need to be stored after each iteration!

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.to_csv()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for this. This assumes having all the data. Example.

```
res = [[1,2,2,2,2],[2,4,4,4,4]]
pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Index','Data1','Data2','Data3','Data4']).to_csv('example.csv',index=False)
```

In case you want to store the new row after each iteration what you can do is:

```
with open('res.csv','w') as f:
   f.write('Index,Data1,Data2,Data3\n')
   # for each iteration
        # compute new row
        f.write(",".join(map(str,row)))
        f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pandas:

```
Import pandas as pd
Import os

x1, x2, x3, x4 = 0, 0, 0, 0
index = 0
Index,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4=[],[],[],[],[]
for i in range(3):
    index += 1
    x1 += 2
    x2 += 2
    x3 += 2
    x4 += 2
    df=pd.DataFrame([index,x1,x2,x3,x4],columns=['Index','Data1','Data2','Data3','Data4'])
    df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False,mode='a')
```

data.csv file:

```
Index,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
1,2,2,2,2
2,4,4,4,4
3,6,6,6,6
```

Comment: @Miradius, edited in response to your edit. It should work now.

Comment: I tried your edited code in python 3.7.4 and get the following error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (5, 5)